# Image from \csvreader cell

Tags: graphics, errors, csvsimple

I want to display the title of the system but also an image of the system.
User will pick system in an Excel file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
selectSystem, systemName
0, Green Apple 
2, Red Apple
0, Banana
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\system}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{grade.csv}{2=\sys}{\sys}}

\begin{document}

Quote for \system \\

%\includegraphics*[viewport=80 70 980 950, scale=0.25]{figures/\system.jpg} %doesn't work

\end{document}
```

I get following error: `! Missing endcsname inserted.`
I believe it is because `\csvreader` doesn't produce a string.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, you just want to remove all whitespaces from the content of the `\system` macro?

Comment: Hi, I played around a bit more and I think, the problem lies more in my reading out the data from csv than white spaces. I.e. if I define `\system` manually with `Green Apple`, it works. (Please see edited question above)

Comment: Whatever the case is classical text processing and file system IO is not the strength of the tex ecosystem. If I would be facing tasks like this i would always choose the lua programming interface or the combination of R, knitr and Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with expansion. You can't expand the macro `\system` inside the `\includegraphics` command. So you need to assign the value to another macro fully expanded using `\edef`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
selectSystem, systemName
0, Green Apple 
2, Red Apple
0, Banana
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand\system{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{grade.csv}{2=\sys}{\edef\MySystem{\sys}}}
\begin{document}

\system % chooses the system

\includegraphics*[viewport=80 70 980 950, scale=0.25]{figures/\MySystem} %now  works

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! Now that it is automated, I have a problem with this line: `\ifthenelse{\equal{\systemtext}{Green Apple}}{\huge}{\Huge}`. It gives me: `! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.` (I get `systemtext` by `\newcommand{\systemtext}{\csvreader[filter equal={\csvcoli}{2}]{\excel}{2=\sys}{\sys}}`

Comment: Hi Alan, I finally understood your code (where I beforehand only copied it): If I use `{\system \ifthenelse{\equal{\MySystem}{Green Apple}}{\huge} {\Huge} }` - it works now. Thanks